# Omitting access specifier in java

Tags: java, class, access-specifier

I know that the name of the `public` class declared in a java file must be same as its file name. But I wonder how this is not giving me a compilation error, rather it is running successfully.

```
class Foo //<-- this can be any name...
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

I know that the default access is `package private`. For the above program, the class name and the file name need not be same. It is executing correctly, rather than a compiler error.
Can anyone throw some light? Thank you.

**EDIT:**

Now I get it! But another question struck me. What happens when there are two such classes in the same file?

Well, I thought a `.class` file will be generated out of the class that has implemented `main` method. There wasn't any compilation error, but to my surprise there wasn't any `.class` file generated either. Why is that so?

Comment: Keep two classes with public access specifier in a single java file. One with main and one without main. You will get warning or error.

Comment: @Rahul: I fail to see how that's relevant to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's absolutely fine. Even for public classes, this is a compiler-specific *optional* restriction.

From [section 7.6 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.6):

> If and only if packages are stored in a file system (§7.2), the host system may choose to enforce the restriction that it is a compile-time error if a type is not found in a file under a name composed of the type name plus an extension (such as .java or .jav) if either of the following is true:
>
> - The type is referred to by code in other compilation units of the package in which the type is declared.
> - The type is declared public (and therefore is potentially accessible from code in other packages).

Note the second bullet point - when your class isn't public, this restriction isn't applicable.

EDIT: From the updated question...

> What happens when there are two such classes in the same file?

Class files are generated based on class names. The presence of a `main` method is *completely irrelevant* to this, as is the original source file name. A class file certainly *should* have been generated if compilation succeeded. Without sample code to reproduce the problem, we can't tell what happened really.

Comment: @nitish712: See my edit, but please try to keep to a single question per post. This is veering dangerously towards the realm of "I keep thinking of something else I want to ask..."

Comment: My bad. The class files were generated.

Answer (score 1):

Your observation is correct. If the class is not public, the name of the class does not need to match the file name. When you don't have a public class in your file, you can name your file as you like.

If you say have a source file Test003.java and you define in it 
two non-public classes AAA and BBB, there are no compilation
errors and two class files are generated: `AAA.class` and `BBB.class`.

So all is good.

```
01/20/2014  06:27 AM               238 AAA.class
01/20/2014  06:27 AM               238 BBB.class
```

[image]

Comment: @nitish712 The whole thing has nothing to do with the presence/absence of main methods. I will check your updated question.